Medical instead of medicine in a chart
If they are listing industries here, shouldn't it be "medicine" instead of "medical"? Medicine, which is a noun, should be used to name a category, shouldn't it?


It is short for 'Medical employment' which is a noun phrase, but a category name doesn't have to be a noun.

I can imagine charts with categories like 'Dead', 'Alive', Sick', Well', 'Employed', 'Unemployed', 'Single', 'Married', 'Christian', 'Hindu', 'Muslim', 'Jewish', etc.

'Medicine' is not the noun form of 'medical'.

So what is the noun form of "medical"? For example, New York Medical University = New York University of ______? I always thought it would be "of Medicine".

It's a "quick and dirty" example  to test whether you understand how such a chart is to be read. I don't think they expect you to be questioning the lack of congruency in their category labels, or that they're comparing apples and oranges when one of the categories is "self-employed".  You could be a self-employed bricklayer or a self-employed software developer.

You need to tell us where you got that otherwise we'll think you made it up.

Lol why would I made this graph up? I mean IELTS materials are all over the place. I would be a freak to draw a graph for myself. The real problem here is sometimes I can't distinguish a real test from a terrible made-up one. I tend to doubt my ability, not the test.

This is not a genuine test resource from IELTS.   Yes, the graph is badly labelled.  For example "Education training" - that probably means "working in education or in training"  so I'd expect "Hotel industry" to mean "working for a hotel or for an industry".  But that's a bit ridiculous.
The category "Business" seems odd, why is the "Hotel industry" specially mentioned? Does Business include everything from office work to retail to delivery and logistics to manufacturing?  What about government workers?  Even a cursory scan shows that the percentages add up to more than 100%
Conclusion: rubbish graph.
